# Material-UI: Style file upload

Tags: css, material-ui

**I am using Material-UI, so this is a little different than conventional styling.**

I am trying to change the color of the button, not the text. However, I'm not sure how to do this using the Material-UI `Input` tag.

Here is my CSS:

```
#uploadFile {
  color: red;
}
```

Here is my upload file using Material-UI.

```
Grid item xs={12}>
                <FormControl>
                  <label>
                  <Input 
                    id='uploadFile'
                    name='uploadFile'
                    type='file'
                    required={true}
                    onChange={(e) => setUploadFile(e.target.files)}
                    />
                    </label>
                </FormControl>
              </Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: Check this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::file-selector-button

Comment: https://material-ui.com/api/input/#main-content